# Check if C++ program is running as an app bundle or command-line on Mac

Tags: c++, objective-c, app-bundle

Is there a way for a C++ or Objective-C program to tell whether is it being run as a command-line application (e.g. with `./myprog` in a shell) or as an app bundle (e.g. by double-clicking on a .app in Finder or running `open myprog.app/` in Terminal)?

Currently I'm using the following.

```cpp
CFBundleRef bundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef bundleUrl = CFBundleCopyBundleURL(bundle);
char bundleBuf[PATH_MAX];
CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(bundleUrl, TRUE, (UInt8*) bundleBuf, sizeof(bundleBuf));
```

At this point, `bundleBuf` now holds the path to the .app bundle *or* the directory containing the command-line executable. I can check whether the string ends with `".app"`, but this is hacky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) of the URL (using `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()` with `kCFURLTypeIdentifierKey`) and see if it conforms to `kUTTypeApplicationBundle` (using `UTTypeConformsTo()`).

```
CFStringRef uti;
if (CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey(bundleUrl, kCFURLTypeIdentifierKey, &uti, NULL) &&
    uti &&
    UTTypeConformsTo(uti, kUTTypeApplicationBundle))
{
    // Is bundled application
}
```

Using Objective-C, you can use the `NSWorkspace` methods `-typeOfFile:error:` and `-type:conformsToType:` for the same purpose.

Comment: Can you post some example C++ of how to use `CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey()`? The documentation doesn't say how to use it, and one of its arguments is a `void*`.

Comment: Thanks, this works! For future readers, the header `#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>` is needed for `kUTTypeApplicationBundle`.

Comment: `kCFURLTypeIdentifierKey` is now deprecated, and I couldn't get this to work for me, so this may not be viable any more.